# Algorithm reductions

Tags: algorithm, class

If I have a algorithm A that i have proven belongs to P can this algorithm also belong to the NPC class or is it strictly P? What about NP? P Belongs to NP right?

Thx for any help!

/Marthin

Comment: Weren't it problems or even more strictly decision problems that belonged to P or NP or NPC? Algorithms have complexity right?

Comment: I dont understand your question?

Comment: Well I have never studied computer science, so what I know is what I could find and read. I might be wrong. According to the definition I found for example in Wikipedia, a complexity class is a set of problems not algorithms. "For example, the class NP is the set of decision problems that can be solved by a non-deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time". Have You ever seen an algorithm for a non-deterministic Turing machine? I don't even know what it means that an algorithm belongs to an NP class. The definition says nothing about algorithms. So I'm asking about it.

Comment: I'v also read the wikipedia page with that given sample and I find it very confusing. But to my understanding an algorithm always belongs to some kind of class. If it belongs to a NP class then it means that if you use a non-deterministic computer (one that always selects the correct answer/path/relation ) to calculate the algorithm it can be done within Non-deterministic Polynomial time.

Comment: According to my understanding an algorithm has some complexity and that's it. It can be polynomial or of some other type. NP is a class of problems. An algorithm for a non-deterministic computer can run in a polynomial time, but it doesn't belong to NP class (because it's not a problem and NP class is a set of problems by definition) And an algorithm for a non-deterministic computer can't run on a deterministic computer at all right? So even putting aside the fact that P is also a class of problems, considering if that algorithm is in P doesn't make sense.

Comment: By NPC did you mean NP-Complete or the complement of NP?  These are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If P!= NP then P is not a subset of NPC, in fact they don't intersect. If P=NP, then P and NPC are the same.  All P algorithms are part of NP though.  Check the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) for more information, and a diagram that explains exactly what you're asking.

If you can prove that P=NP, you will be very famous.

Comment: P is not a subset of NPC(I presume that means NP-Complete) depends on whether P = NP or not. If P != NP, then P and NPC do not intersect, otherwise they are the same! Please clarify that.